# Relation between sorted weights of spanning tree and minimal spanning tree

Tags: optimization, algorithms, trees

Let $ G=(V,E) $ be a graph, $T$ a **minimal** spanning tree for $G$ and $T'$ **some** spanning tree of $G$.

Let us denote:

$w_1\leq w_2\leq ... \leq w_{n-1}$ the weights of $T$

$w'_1\leq w'_2\leq ... \leq w'_{n-1}$ the weights of $T'$

Prove/Disprove: for every $i$ the following holds: $w_i \leq w'_i$

====

Need some guidance/help figuring this out. so far I tried disproving for a while but with no success, then I thought maybe I could assume there exists $w'_i <w_i$ and somehow by adding it to $T$ and examining the cycle it creates I could get to a contradiction...

Comment: Is not that just simple arithmetic property of inequality?

Comment: @MariaMazur
let T weights be 1,2,3,4 (adds to 10)
let T' weights be 3,3,3,3 (adds to 12)

but the last weight holds 3<4

Comment: @Limitless didn't you just answer your own question?

Comment: @grendelsdad no, since my example might not exist, it is possible that it would lead to a contradiction for T being minimal.

Comment: @Limitless yes, you're right. Sorry. I see what you mean, this feels like it should be easier than it is...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you requested some guidance/help, I won't go into details (I may do it later if you would like to). Your idea is good, let's suppose there exists an $i$ such that $w_i' < w_i$. Let the edge corresponding to $w_i'$ be $e_i'$. By examining the addition of $e_i'$ to $T$ and the cycle it creates is not enough to get a contradiction, because it can happen that $e_i'$ has the largest weight in that cycle.

Instead, we can use the simple claim stating that every MST of a graph can be the output of Kruskal's algorithm. Now let $i$ be the smallest of such indices, i.e. it is true that $w_j \leq w_j'$ for all $j < i$ and $w_i > w_i'$. The question you should try to investigate is after putting $i-1$ edges to $T$, how can it happen that Kruskal's algorithm puts $e_i$ to $T$ (where $e_i$ is the edge corresponging to $w_i$)? Using the fact that each of $T$ and $T'$ is a tree you can have a contradiction.

**Edit 1: More details**

Let the subgraph of $T$ spanned by $e_1,...,e_{i-1}$ be denoted by $U$, and let the subgraph of $T'$ spanned by $e_{1}',...,e_{i}'$ be denoted by $U'$. As $T$ and $T'$ are trees, $U$ and $U'$ are forests (not necessarily connected). Let the number of components of $U$ be denoted by $c$, while the number of components of $U'$ is $c'$.

First note that because the edges are sorted by their weights, $w_{j}' \leq w_{i}' < w_i$ for all $j \leq i$. If Kruskal's algorithm puts $e_i$ to $T$, that means that $U \cup e_{j}'$ must contain a cycle, for all $j \leq i$. This can happen only if all $e_{j}'$ edges are inside the components of $U$ (they cannot be between components because that would not create a cycle in $U$). Hence, $c' \geq c$, and the number of nodes in $U$ must equal to the number of nodes in $U'$ (denoted by $n$).

As $U$ has $i-1 = n - c$ edges, while $U'$ has $i = n - c'$ edges, this leads to $i-1 = n - c \geq  n - c' = i$, and we have our contradiction (we used the fact that a forest containing $n$ nodes and $c$ components has exactly $n-c$ edges).

Comment: Thanks! it helped indeed. I didn't thought of using Kruskal' "greediness" as an argument for the proof.

Comment: @rss Can you explain the contradiction?

Comment: @UmShmum see Edit 1, please.